# Using module (which is collector of modules) in particular module

Tags: fortran, gfortran

This is my code:

```
Program Module_in_module

Use Module_collection

Implicit none

! Something...

End Program Module_in_module

Module Module_collection

Use Number_01
Use Number_02

End Module Module_collection

Module Number_01

Implicit none

! Something......

End Module Number_01

Module Number_02

Use Module_collection

Implicit none

! Something......

End Module Number_02
```

I have an intention to use module `Module_collection` like one module which use all rest modules in the project. For example, if I want to use, in some other module, which is already in `Module_collection`, all modules from project with `Use Module_collection` i got this message:
`Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'module_collection.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory`
Is there any equivalent for `Only: Some_varable` which can be used for excluding module with using `Module_collection` (Use all others modules in project but only exclude just, in this case, `Module Number_02`?

Comment: Is that all one source file?

Comment: Have you put the modules in separate files? This would make compilation easier to debug.

Comment: They are in separate files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  The error message doesn't seem related to what you are asking.  That said, it seems you're asking something along the lines of `use module, all_but : ...` (say) to exclude rather than include?

Comment: How to use all modules from project in module `Number_02`?

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark
I also got this message: 
`it seems you have a circular dependency in Fortran files. Check your USE or INCLUDE statements.`

Comment: Such an option will probably not help you. First concentrate to identifying what is really happening and why you have an error. Only then try solutions. Otherwise you are solving an XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: I can not understand what is not clear in my question? If it is possible to use module collector? How can i use that module in separate module file correctly (That module is incorporeted in module collector)? Is it possible at all?

Comment: One of your comments contains vital information which immediately illuminates the source of your problem -- that is what is not clear in your question.  You've asked enough questions, and had enough answers, to know better by now.

Comment: @Judge_Dredd You say that your question is clear: *"If it is possible to use module collector?"* But that is not true! It is not clear! In your question you are asking something completely different: *"Is there any equivalent for Only: Some_varable which can be used for excluding module with using Module_collection (Use all others modules in project but only exclude just, in this case, Module Number_02?"* This is very different and therefore it is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Now you tell us

> I also got this message: it seems you have a circular dependency in
>   Fortran files. Check your USE or INCLUDE statements.

and your error is blindingly obvious.  The module `module_collection` uses module `number_02` and module `number_02` uses module `module_collection`.  Since Fortran requires that a module be compiled before it is referenced (in a `use` statement) and since there is this circular dependency the compiler can't continue.

Resolve the circular dependency.  It looks a bit odd that the the collector is referenced by one of its collection.

I expect this is a duplicate of another question I haven't found yet.